# Visual studio 16.6.1 doesn't show color of the methods and actions

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I updated `Visual Studio` to `16.6.1` version and it doesn't show color of the **Methods** and **Actions**

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by change the `Editor Color Scheme` from **Visual Studio 2017** to **Visual Studio 2019**

`Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Editor Color Scheme`

[image]

**Result :**

[image]